# select row_id with a specific value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, combinations

I need to retrieve all the row_ids if one of the values in columnn `AST = 'undefined'`.

```
SELECT ROW_ID 
 FROM TABLE WHERE AST='unedefined'
```

does not work. It only shows one row, but I want all rows with that same `ROW_ID` to be fetched.

This is my table:

```html
<TABLE BORDER="1">
<TR> <TH>ROW_ID</TH> <TH>GENDER2</TH> <TH>RelNum</TH> <TH>Date</TH> <TH>VALUE</TH> 
<TR> <TD>1</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>12</TD><TD>12/12/2014</TD><TD>undefined</TD>  
<TR> <TD>1</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>12</TD><TD>13/12/2014</TD><TD></TD>
<TR> <TD>2</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>45</TD><TD>12/12/2014</TD><TD>54</TD>
<TR> <TD>3</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>56</TD><TD>13/23/2024</TD><TD>999</TD>
<TR> <TD>3</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>56</TD><TD>12/12/2014</TD><TD>undefined</TD>
 </TABLE>
    And I only want to see this in return:
  
  <TABLE BORDER="1">
<TR> <TH>ROW_ID</TH> <TH>GENDER2</TH> <TH>RelNum</TH> <TH>Date</TH> <TH>VALUE</TH> 
<TR> <TD>1</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>12</TD><TD>12/12/2014</TD><TD>undefined</TD>  
<TR> <TD>1</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>12</TD><TD>13/12/2014</TD><TD></TD>
<TR> <TD>3</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>56</TD><TD>13/23/2024</TD><TD>999</TD>
<TR> <TD>3</TD> <TD>M</TD> <TD>56</TD><TD>12/12/2014</TD><TD>undefined</TD>
```

Comment: I have a strange feeling of "déjà vu". Don't you already have posted the same (or very similar) question yesterday?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392128/select-all-columns-row-id-if-a-column-value-is-met-in-one-of-the-rows-with-the-s (deleted)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  * 
from    table 
where   row_id in (
        select  row_id 
        from table 
        where ast = 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table t
where exists
(
  select 1
  from table t2
  where t2.row_id = t.row_id
    and t2.ast = 'undefined'
);
```